# Hyperlink in existing PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdf-annotations

I am trying to add a hyperlink based off of known position coordinates in the PDF. I have tried editing the physical pdf code and have added a link, but in the process deleted other content on the pdf.

```
[/Rect [ x x x x ]                     
    /Action                                     
  <</Subtype /URI/URI (http://www.xxxxx.com/)>>
    /Subtype /Link                              
/ANN pdfmark
```

Is there any way of adding the hyperlink without corrupting the existing pdf? Would converting to a different file format adding the link and converting back be a better approach? Possible commercial use prevents use of some gnu licensed products.

Comment: That should be possible with any general purpose PDF library.

Answer (score 1):

[Debenu Quick PDF Libarary](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/trial/) also provides a solution. I also recommend to don't edit the 'physical code' of the PDF file (with Notepad or others), because it won't give any solution - neither in other cases.

Here is a sample code how to do it with the Debenu Quick PDF Library:

```
/* Add a link to a webpage*/

// Set the origin for the co-ordinates to be the top left corner of the page.

DPL.SetOrigin(1);

// Adding a link to an external web page using the AddLinkToWeb function.

DPL.AddLinkToWeb(200, 100, 60, 20, "www.debenu.com", 0);

// Hyperlinks and text are two separate elements in a PDF, 
//so we'll draw some text now so that you know 
//where the hyperlink is located on the page.

DPL.DrawText(205, 114, "Click me!");

// When the Debenu Quick PDF Library object is initiated a blank document
// is created and selected in memory by default. So
// all we need to do now is save the document to
// the local hard disk to see the changes that we've made.

DPL.SaveToFile("link_to_web.pdf");
```

Member of Debenu

Answer (score 0):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can add hyperlinks to existing PDFs. The library is **not** *GPL-licensed  and can be used in commercial solutions after purchasing a license.

Below is a code that adds hyperlink on to the first page of a PDF.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

public static void AddHyperlink()
{
    // NOTE: 
    // When used in trial mode, the library imposes some restrictions.
    // Please visit http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/trial-restrictions.aspx
    // for more information.

    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument("input.pdf"))
    {
        PdfPage page = pdf.Pages[0];
        RectangleF rectWithLink = new RectangleF(10, 70, 200, 100);
        page.AddHyperlink(rectWithLink, new Uri("http://google.com"));

        pdf.Save("output.pdf");
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Comment: GPL does not prevent _commercial_ applications, but most kinds of _proprietary_ applications.